# SQLAlchemy Relationship with Composite Joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to find the right way to specify a relationship between SQL alchemy tables that join on conditions from two related tables.

I have a SQL statment equivalent to:

```
select a.id
     , b.id
     , b.b_val
     , c.id
     , c.c_dt
     , c.c_val
from a
join b
  on a.id = b.id
join c
  on b.id = c.id
  and a.date <-= c.date
  and a.date < current_date;
```

What I am currently getting out of SQLAlchemy is:

```
print(q)

SELECT schema.a.id AS schema_a_id
     , schema.b.id AS schema_b_id
     , schema.b.b_val AS schema_b_b_val
     , schema.c.id AS schema_c_id
     , schema.c.c_dt AS schema_c_c_dt
     , schema.c.c_val AS schema_c_c_val 
FROM schema.a 
JOIN schema.b 
  ON schema.a.id = schema.b.id 
JOIN schema.c 
  ON schema.a.secondary_id = schema.c.id
  -- I'm missing the rest of the join clause here
```

I'm getting thrown off by the join condition to the `c` table.  In it I want to use a constraint on the date column with two conditions.  I attempted to do this using the `primaryjoin` field in my relationship but so far no luck.

Here's my minimum reproducible example:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'schema'}
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    secondary_id = Column(Integer())
    a_dt = Column(Date())
    b_rel = relationship('b', uselist=False, back_populates="a")
    c_rel = relationship('c', primaryjoin="and_(a.a_dt >= c.c_dt, a.a_dt < func.current_date())")

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'schema'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.id), primary_key=True)
    b_val = Column(Integer())

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'schema'}
    id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(A.secondary_id), primary_key=True)
    c_dt = Column(Date())
    c_val = Column(Integer())

engine = create_engine('teradatasql://'+user+':'+pswd+'@'+host)

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
sess = Session()

q = sess.query(A.id, B.id, B.b_val, C.id, C.c_dt, C.c_val).join(B).join(C)

# result is shown above
```

What am I missing that I could add to cause this relationship to function properly?

Comment: Given an entity [`Query.join()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) will attempt to join using natural foreign key relationships between the two, so you'd want to pass `A.c_rel` instead, but that is not going to work either given your models, which seem to disagree with your desired query.

Comment: How do the models disagree with the desired query?  That is what I am trying to determine.

Comment: The primary join of `A.c_rel` is slightly different from your desired SQL and in it you join `c` on `b.id`, though `c` and `b` have no direct foreign key relationship. I'm not entirely sure how you'd have to express having `b` in the join from `A` to `C` in this case.